# Ajax request not being triggered by event handler

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have this script :

```
class Notifications
    constructor: ->
        @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
        @setup() if @notifications.length > 0 

    setup: -> 
        $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick

        $.ajax(
            url: "/notifications.json"
            dataType: "JSON"
            method: "GET"
            success: @handleSuccess
        )
    handleClick: (e) =>
        $.ajax(
            url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
            dataType: "JSON"
            method: "POST"
            success: ->
                $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text("")                
        )
    handleSuccess: (data) =>
       console.log(data) 
       items = $.map data, (notification) ->
            "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#{notification.url}'>#{notification.actor} #{notification.action} #{notification.notifiable.type}</a>"
        console.log(items)

        $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)
        if items.length is 0
            $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text("")               

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', -> new Notifications)
```

That works fine besides for the .on "click" event call which doesn't trigger the @handleClick function. Any thoughts?

Comment: So your `constructor` gets called (i.e. the `turbolinks:load` event is happening as expected) but `handleClick` never gets called? Are you sure you have a `data-behavior="notifications-link"` element?

Comment: Yes, the GET request which retrieves json works, it generates the html designated in the script, and from what I can tell everything else works fine except this one part

Comment: But is that element there when you say `new Notifications`? If your `GET /notifications.json` is generating the `data-behavior="notifications-link"` element then you either have to use the delegation form of jQuery's `on` or move that call into the `handleSuccess` function.

Comment: I'm not a CoffeeScript expert, but don't you want `$("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").click ->`

Comment: @muistooshort isn't it already in the delegated form? and you mean I ought to move the .on "click" into the handleSuccess?

Comment: The delegation form would look like `$(some_ancestor).on('click', "[data-behavior='notifications-link']", -> ...)` where `some_ancestor` is a selector for something that is always there and will contain the `"[data-behavior='notifications-link']"` elements. See [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Alternatively, add the elements to the DOM and then bind your click handler in `handleSuccess`.

Comment: The first suggestion still didn't work. Could you elaborate a bit more on your second suggestion please? thank you